# Sum and product of certain prime sequences

Tags: number-theory

Let $p_k$ is the $k$th prime.

What are good estimates for the following?

$$S_k=1+\frac{1}{\log_23}+\frac{1}{\log_25}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\log_2p_{k-1}}+\frac{1}{\log_2p_k}$$
$$P_k=1\cdot\frac{1}{\log_23}\cdot\frac{1}{\log_25}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{1}{\log_2p_{k-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{\log_2p_k}$$

$$\tilde{S}_k=1+\frac{1}{\log_22}+\frac{1}{\log_23}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\log_2{k-1}}+\frac{1}{\log_2k}$$
$$\tilde{P}_k=1\cdot\frac{1}{\log_22}\cdot\frac{1}{\log_23}\cdot\cdots\cdot\frac{1}{\log_2{k-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{\log_2k}$$

Comment: I tried to look for references. I could not get any for series involving logarithms.

Comment: For the sums, I would approximate it by an integral.

Comment: The last two can be easily bounded with integrals. For the product, take the logarithm first.

Comment: Thank you but I am very unfamiliar with integral techniques. @JimmyK4542 If I take log, then the series becomes even more messy with double logs.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679344/product-of-the-logarithms-of-primes

Comment: "integral techniques" just means comparing $\int_r^s f(t)\,dt$ with $\sum_r^{s-1}f(n)$; the former can be interpreted as the area under a curve, the latter, as the sum of the areas of a number of rectangles. If $f$ is monotone, you can say quite a lot about the comparison. You can also look up Euler-Maclaurin summation. Also, you'll probably find something about your first sum in any intro analytic number theory text, possibly also in Hardy and Wright.

Comment: You can convert the sums to natural logarithms quite easily

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes sure I can do that. Is there a term for these series?